# How to write a helper type for result_of in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

```
template<typename F,typename...X>
using Result_of = typename result_of<F(X...)>::type;

int ff(int){return 2;}
typedef bool(*PF)(int);
auto fx = [](char ch){return tolower(ch);};
Result_of<decltype(&ff)()> r1 = 7;
Result_of<PF(int)> r2 = 2;
Result_of<decltype(fx)(char)> r5 = "a";
```

When I compile with gcc, I get the following error:

```
main.cpp: In substitution of 'template<class F, class ... X> using Result_of = typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type [with F = int (*())(int); X = {}]':
main.cpp:17:30:   required from here
main.cpp:6:57: error: function returning a function
 using Result_of = typename std::result_of<F(X...)>::type;
                                                         ^
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong with this line:

```
Result_of<decltype(&ff)()> r1 = 7;
```

First, `Result_of` takes a function type and a list of arguments, comma separated. You're not providing them that way. So it's interpreting `F` to be `(int)(*)(int)()`, which would be a pointer to a function taking an `int` returning a function returning an `int`. But it's illegal in C++ to have a function return a function, hence the error.

Second, `ff` takes an `int`, not nothing. Lastly, `ff` decays to a pointer-to-function and you need the actual *function*. The correct expression would be:

```
Result_of<decltype(*ff), int> r1 = 7;
```

Similarly, the next need to be:

```
Result_of<PF, int> r2 = 2;
Result_of<decltype(fx), char> r5 = 'a'; // fx returns an int, so you 
                                        // can't assign a const char* to it
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the OP wants to use the comma separated version?

Comment: @Yakk I don't know what else OP could want?

Comment: `template<class Sig> using Result_of=typename std::result_of<Sig>::type;` is my guess, as that makes his use cases compile as-is.

Comment: @Yakk Ah. Yeah, I guess I was answering why given his implementation of `Result_of`, nothing worked.

Comment: @Yakk I use the comma version because I have more complicated functions. Here I try to keep it simple. Your explanation is awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is:

```
template<class Sig>
using Result_of = typename std::result_of<Sig>::type;
```

will make your use cases "work".  Some will fail to compile because you passed in the wrong signature, or the types don't match.

However it isn't the best way to do it.

C++11 compilers do not all implement the best-practices version of `result_of`: namely, a SFINAE friendly one.  If you are writing a helper, I do it in best-practices style.

First, an alias to do `decltype` evaluation:

```
template<class F, class...Args>
using invoke_result = decltype( std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...));
```

Next, some metaprogramming boilerplate I find useful:

```
namespace details {
  template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
  template<class...Ts>using void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;

  template<template<class...>class Z, class, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply=details::can_apply<Z,void,Ts...>;
```

`can_apply< template, args... >` answers the question "is applying the args... to the template valid?".  This is surprisingly useful.

As we are in C++11 land, an `enable_if_t` alias makes code look prettier:

```
template<bool b, class T=void>
using enable_if_t=typename std::enable_if<b,T>::type;
```

We can now start working on a `result_of_t` alias:

```
namespace details {
  template<class Sig,class=void>
  struct result_of {};
  template<class F, class...Args>
  struct result_of<
    F(Args...),
    enable_if_t<can_apply<invoke_result, F, Args...>>
  > {
    using type=invoke_result<F,Args...>;
  };
}
template<class Sig>
using result_of_t = typename details::result_of<Sig>::type;
```

and we are done.

This generates a SFINAE friendly type alias called `result_of_t` that works like a high quality C++14 `std::result_of_t` in any compliant C++11 compiler.  It won't work well on MSVC, but that is because MSVC2015 still doesn't implement C++11 sufficiently.

All of your examples should work with the above `result_of_t` replacing `Result_of`, or fail because they are invalid.

```
int ff(int){return 2;}
typedef bool(*PF)(int);
auto fx = [](char ch){return tolower(ch);};

result_of_t<decltype(&ff)()> r1 = 7;
```

this fails, because you have to pass an `int` to `ff`.  This would work:

```
result_of_t<decltype(&ff)(int)> r1 = 7;

result_of_t<PF(int)> r2 = 2;
```

this assigns `2` to a `bool`.  So it ... works.

```
result_of_t<decltype(fx)(char)> r5 = "a";
```

this assigns `"a"` to an `int`, which is probably not what you want.  (`tolower` returns an `int` in C/C++).

We can fix this via:

```
auto fx = [](char ch)->char{return tolower(ch);};
result_of_t<decltype(fx)(char)> r5 = 'a';
```

Comment: Well, almost compile. Still need to add `int` to `decltype(&ff)()` and still can't assign `"a"` to an `int`.

Comment: @Barry s/compile/work/, for values of work including "no, that makes no sense".