# Check if a given type has a inner template rebind

Tags: c++, templates, boost, template-meta-programming

I need a trait which will check if a given type has an inner template named `rebind` which takes a single template type parameter. Something like:

```
template <typename X>
struct has_rebind
{
    static const bool value = /* ??? */;
};
```

This is similar to what [BOOST_TTI_HAS_TEMPLATE](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/tti/doc/html/the_type_traits_introspection_library/tti_detail_has_template.html) does, but I want to implement the trait without the use of Boost TTI, and I do not know how that macro is implemented.

Comment: What specific inner name are you looking for, with what parameters?

Comment: I am looking for name "rebind" which take single <typename> parameter.

Comment: You do know that boost is opensource, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++11 and up gives us a wealth of alternatives with which to write arbitrarily complex type traits in fairly simple fashion. One such is [`void_t`](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3911.pdf):

```
template <typename... >
using void_t = void;
```

All you do is write a base trait:

```
template <typename X, typename = void>
struct has_rebind : std::false_type { };
```

and then a partial specialization that will only pass template deduction if the criteria you want is met, namely that `X` has a `rebind<T>`. In this case, the type doesn't matter, so we can just pick one:

```
template <typename X>
struct has_rebind<X, void_t<typename X::template rebind<int>>>
: std::true_type { };
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5de36dc609f5114b)

---

A different approach to the same thing is [Yakk's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31348065/2069064) `can_apply`, which with some boilerplate:

```
namespace details {
  template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
  template<class...Ts>using void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;

  template<template<class...>class Z, class, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply=details::can_apply<Z,void,Ts...>;
```

We can write something similar:

```
template <typename X, typename T>
using rebind_t = typename X::template rebind<T>;

template <typename X>
using has_rebind = can_apply<rebind_t, X, int>;
```

[<kbd>Demo 2</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43e5796f0b2ca3f4)