# why is void_t necessary to check for the existence of a member type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

When reading [Barry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31744397/678093) to [Check if a given type has a inner template rebind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744212/check-if-a-given-type-has-a-inner-template-rebind), I thought:

Why do we need `void_t` at  all?

Why does the following **not** work?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename X, typename Y = X>
struct has_rebind : std::false_type {};

template <typename X>
struct has_rebind<X, typename X::template rebind<int>> : std::true_type {};

struct A { };
struct B { template <typename > struct rebind { }; };

int main() {
    std::cout << has_rebind<A>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_rebind<B>::value << std::endl;
}
```

**output**

```
0
0
```

<kbd>[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4308bfc48cf4e22)</kbd>

Comment: [How does `void_t` work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27687389/3953764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In those lines:

```
template <typename X, typename Y = X>
struct has_rebind : std::false_type {};

template <typename X>
struct has_rebind<X, typename X::template rebind<int>> : std::true_type {};
```

the default type (`X`) and the one you provided for specialization (`typename X::template rebind<int>`) must be the same type. Since void is a pretty good "default dummy type", it's often used as the default type and we use `void_t` to change whatever was given in the specialization

Comment: I missed the fact about the "same type", thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 11):

`void_t` is a hack.

How template class specialization pattern matching works is that the primary template determines the kind (type or value) of each argument, and the defaults:

```
template<class A, class B=A, class C=void>
struct whatever {};
```

For you to invoke `whatever<?...>`, you must match the valid arguments to the primary specialization of `whatever<?...>`.

After that test is passed, the various specializations are pattern matched against.  So suppose you wanted to have a specialization for pointers.

```
template<class T>
struct whatever<T*, T*, void> {
```

the `template<?...>` argument list here isn't matched against: that just provides a list of "free variables".  the pattern matching comes within the `<?...>` template argument list after the **`whatever`** class name.  Each argument is matched in turn against the arguments sent to `whatever`, and from that pattern matching the "free variables" (`class T` above) are determined.

The trick is that you can put expressions in here that do not pattern match, but rely on other pattern matches, and then produce a new type:

```
template<class T>
struct whatever<T*, typename std::add_const<T>::type*, void> {
```

the second argument is a dependent type (of the template `add_const`), so cannot be pattern matched against.  In general, the result of `some_template<T>::type` can be a Turing complete non-injective computation: the C++ standard does not require that to be inverted, fortunately for compiler writers.

The compiler doesn't try -- instead, it tries to determine `T` from other template arguments, and then substitutes `T` in for that argument, and checks that it matches the types passed to `whatever`.

The trick here is that substitution failure (in the immediate context) doesn't generate an error<sup>1</sup>.  If `std::add_const<T>` did not have a field called `::type`, instead of generating an error it would instead say "well, this pattern doesn't match".  It would discard this specialization as being a viable one from the set of candidates.

This feature was added way back in the early days of C++ because template functions would greedily match even basic types, and attempts to use derived types (say, `iterator::value_type`) would fail if you passed an `int` as `iterator`.  With this feature, the fact that `int` has no `::value_type` would mean "this isn't a valid overload of some template function", rather than a syntax error during overload resolution.  In effect, template functions where nearly useless without it if there was any overloading going on, so they added SFINAE -- substitution failure is not an error.

Once it showed up, people started abusing it.  `void_t` attempts to exploit it.

```
template<class T>
struct whatever<T*, T*, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().hello_world())>> {
```

`void_t` takes its type argument(s), and discards them, and produces `void` *in a dependent context* (thus blocking the expression from being used to deduce `T`).  It does so in a way that first evaluates the type arguments<sup>2</sup>, which means that if the type produced causes a failure in the immediate context, you get a substitution failure.

A point of this is that the type produced doesn't matter once you feed it through `void_t`.  We might not even know what type of `t.hello_world()` should be when we define the primary specialization of `whatever<?...>`.  So we discard it and turn it into `void`.  In order for the specialization to match, the type must match.  So we set the type to `void` in the primary specialization, and in the specializations we do a test then pass it to `void_t` to throw away the type result.

We can also use `std::enable_if_t<?>` with a compile-time `bool` expression, which also produces the type `void` if and only if that `bool` is true (and otherwise fails in the immediate context).

In a sense, `void_t` maps valid type expressions to `void`, and invalid type expressions to a substitution failure.  `enable_if_t` maps `true` to `void`, and `false` to a substitution failure.  In both cases, you need the `void` type in the specialization to "consume" the result and match properly.

Both are highly useful in SFINAE code, which is a powerful feature that lets you make decisions about which specialization to use based off something other than simple pattern matching.

---

<sup>1</sup> Last I checked, [this requirement was not explicitly in the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30676839/1774667)!  The SFINAE rules applied to template function substitution failures, and everyone (including compiler writers and standard writers) just assumed it applied to template class substitution failures.  Of course, the standard is hard enough to read I probably just missed it.

<sup>2</sup> At one point, various compilers disagreed with what `template<class...>using void_t=void;` should do exactly.  Some would fail if the expression passed was a substitution failure: others would note that the expression would be discarded, and discard it before checking for substitution failure.  This was clarified in a defect report.

Comment: Wow, that's one comprehensive answer! I didn't know about your first footnote, I'd be interested if someone confirms or infirms whether SFINAE rules for templated classes are in the standard or not.

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you so much!
One thing I still can't get. You stated that compiler does not try to detect dependant type, so how can it understand that void_t<?...> actually produces void?

Comment: @dmit it produces it from other non dependant arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! But even without the `void_t<might_be_a_type_or_not>`, directly putting the `might_be_a_type_or_not` (without the `void_t`) seems can still SFINAE, and discard the matching without any issue? Then why `void_t` is necessary?

Comment: @dragonxlwang Because the 3rd argument of `whatever<a,b>` is `void`, not `might_be_a_type_or_not`: see the primary specialization of `whatever`, where the 3rd argument is defaulted to `void`.  So the specialization won't match.  By doing `void_t<might_be_a_type_or_not>`, it becomes `void` if it is a type, and SFINAE if not.

Comment: I see, so in the case of the match, still requires the third template argument to be of type `void`, matching the primary definition in order to invoke `whatever` with only one argument, and the other two filled by default argument deduced. without `void_t`, it simply won't compile for classes without `hellow_world`; However, if the intention is to check if `T` has *public* member function of `f`, that takes no parameter input, and returns `void`, then `void_t` would not be needed?

Answer (score 3):

Your example doesn't work because `has_rebind<A>` and `has_rebind<B>` both have a single template argument, so the second argument is defaulted:
`has_rebind<A,A>` and `has_rebind<B,B>`. Now you do provide a specialization of `has_rebind<X, X::rebind<int>>` but that specialization isn't used when instantiating `has_rebind<B,B>`.

You'd need something like [`typename Y = typename X::template rebind<int>`](http://ideone.com/ShKlkT) to trigger your specialization, but that fails to compile for `A`.